# Target first and last element with class out of all nested

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to target only the first and the last span with a class 'target' in CSS. Code structure is like:

```html
<td>
  <span>Target 1</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="target">Target 2</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="target">Target 3</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="target">Target 4</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Target 5</span>
</td>
```

So in this case my goal is to style only 'Target 2' and 'Target 4' and leave 'Target 3' as it is . Problem is that :first-child, :nth-child() and :first-of-type (and their equivalents for last), in every possible combination so far, has found and styled all three elements with class 'target', probably because each of them is first nested (in td) element with class='target'.

Any idea how to target those two elements in CSS/SCSS? (it is a dynamic table, there may be more td elements)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible using pure CSS

Answer (score 0):

```css
.target:nth-child(even){color:red;}
```

```html
<td>
  <span>Target 1</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="target">Target 2</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="target">Target 3</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="target">Target 4</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Target 5</span>
</td>
```

Comment: It would work, but in this case it is possible that there will be more elements, as table is dynamic. Sorry, my bad, forgot to mention that.